# How to get columns to break into rows with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this form with four input elements in a row (in desktop view).

Can anybody tell me how to get those four input elements to break into rows when the screen width gets below, say, 680px?

```css
form {
  display: flex;
}
input {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a media query with a breakpoint of 680px and `flex-direction:column;`

```css
form {
  display: flex;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  form {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, flex items line up in a row. An initial value on a flex container is `flex-direction: row`.

Switching to `flex-direction: column` is one good method for stacking items vertically. This method is already covered in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39509000/3597276).

Another method would be to enable `flex-wrap` and give each input `width: 100%`.

This would allow only one input per row, forcing subsequent inputs to wrap.

```css
form { display: flex;}

input { width: 25%; }

@media ( max-width: 680px ) {
  form { flex-wrap: wrap; }
  input { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</form>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5x6dyfxL/)